# mpg123 link error "_read" and "_lseek"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I compile mpg123  lib in win32.
It don't want it linked to  MSVCR90.DLL

I change:
C/C++ ->  "ignore all default libraries"   to YES

add   "additional dependencies"  ==>  libcmt.lib

"C/C++ -> Runtime Library "from   "multi-threaded DLL" to  "Multi-threaded"

But i  still get this error:

Please help me.

```
readers.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _read
readers.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lseek
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be linking to `LIBCPMT.LIB` which is the CPP standard library.

Comment: resolved.  Thanks .   Use the default /MT will work. i still don't know why i get those errors before,when i did as upstairs.